# offset property not centering the Col element using Reactstrap

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a page in React, using Reactstrap documentation (it is the same as Bootstrap 4). I want that the 3 columns are in one single Row if the screen is large, when the screen is medium the first 2 of them being in the same Row and the last one centered below and, finally, when the screen is small or extra-small, then 3 of them each one on a single Row.
The problem is that I centered the 3rd column using the offset property (only for the md screen) but somehow even when the screen is large it seems the offset is applied and there are still 2 Rows. Why?

CODE

```
class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
     <div>
        <div className="App">
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <br/>
          <br/>
            <img src={'ff'} />
            <br/>
          </div>
            <br/>
            <br/><br/>
            <Container className="prova centered" fluid>
              <Row>
                <Col className="frame" xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={4}>
                  <Card className="card">
                  <CardImg className="cards" src={tile1} />
                    <CardBody>
                      <CardTitle> Recruitment Services</CardTitle>
                      <CardText>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</CardText>
                      <Button>Discover More!</Button>
                    </CardBody>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
                <Col className="frame" xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={4}>
                  <Card>
                  <CardImg className="cards" src={tile2} alt="Card image cap" />
                    <CardBody>
                      <CardTitle>Web Design and Web-mastering</CardTitle>
                      <CardText>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</CardText>
                      <Button>Discover More!</Button>
                    </CardBody>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
                <Col className="frame" xs={12} sm={{size: 7, offset: 3}} md={4} lg={4}>
                  <Card>
                  <CardImg className="frame cards" src={tile3} alt="Card image cap" />
                    <CardBody>
                      <CardTitle>Digital Marketing</CardTitle>
                      <CardText>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</CardText>
                      <Button>Discover More!</Button>
                    </CardBody>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
              </Row>
              </Container>
              <br/>
              <br/>
     </div>

    );
  }

}


export default App;
```

Screens
[image: XS Screen]

[image: Medium screens]

[image: Large screen]

Comment: I'm guessing it's because your offset is 3, size is 7, and there's 12 columns. Which means you have 3 col, then 7 col, then 2 col. If you want the element centered, it's size would need to be 6.

Comment: mmm, it still does not display on a signle row when the screen is large though.... Also, is size the same as writing sm={4} so size:4?